# Actionbar перекрывает часть фрагметна

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, actionbar

Всем доброго времени суток) Вопрос следующий. Есть активити с табами, и при загрузке фрагмента в котейнер, фрагмент содержащий ListView уползает под ActionBar (ну тот что с табами) тем самым перекрывая часть контента. Как это исправить? Заранее благодарен за ответ :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.kombo.eplog.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />





</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Предоставьте свою xml разметку, пожалуйста

Comment: попробуйте так
<include layout="@layout/content_main" app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

Comment: К сожалению не помогло ):

Answer (score 0):

У вас разметка странная немного. Попробуйте это:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.kombo.eplog.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

В зависимости от реализации добавьте в Ваш xml основной активности

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```